# Is there notation for '$x$, where $x$ has an equal probability of being $1$, $2$ or $3$'?

Tags: probability, notation

Basically the question is in the title, something like '$x$, where $x = [1(1/3), 2[1/3], 3[1/3]]$'.

Guess it could be notated as a random integer between $1$ and $3$, if notation exists for that.

This is for an art installation not a mathematics paper, so apologies if the question seems dumb but I want to use existing notation if it exists. :)

Comment: It's common to see $P[x = 1] = P[x = 2] = P[x = 3] = 1/3$, where $P[x = i]$ is "the probability that $x$ equals $i$".

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this particular part of the art installation? Notation tends to be pretty flexible and the purpose of "The symbols should look like written math" vs. "The symbols should look like scratch work" vs. "The symbols should communicate something mathematical" would probably lead to different answers. (Also, it depends how much space you have)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a variable has [a discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution), so you may write $X\sim \mathcal{U}\{1,\,3\}$ (random variables are usually capitalised).

Comment: (+1) Same answer :)

Comment: Thank you - so a dice roll would be X∼U{1,6}?

Comment: @Wilskt Yes that's it.

Comment: @Wilskt Just be careful to use braces, because with round brackets you'll get the notation for a continuous uniform distribution.

Answer (score 4):

There is the notation $X\sim_\Bbb P\mathcal{U}(S)$ to indicate that $X$ follows the uniform distribution on a set $S$. In you case this would give $$X\sim_\Bbb P\mathcal{U}(\{1,2,3\})$$
Some would also write $$X\sim_\Bbb P\mathcal{U}\{1,3\}$$
as indicated in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution).